# Getting exception - TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null TypeError:

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am new to this and would appreciate any help that I can get. SO i have a requirement in Sharepoint list. where i need to color columns when any task is overdue . I have a Datetime Column which is a calculated field in sharepoint and a Status column which is a drop down-
I am using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
            var today = new Date();
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                var status = rows[i]["Status"];
                var dateDue= new Date(rows[i]["DateTime"]);
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                if(dateDue<today&&status!="Complete"){
                    row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now when i edit the date or the Status field in any of the items in my sharepoint list. I get the following exception
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of nullTypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of null

When i load the list again--It works fine and it colors the field in yellow if the criteria is met. Why am i getting this exception.

Comment: How do you edit the list item?In quick edit or edit form?

Comment: I tired in both the forms and it fails in both. But Mostly use Edit Form

Comment: This is a list view csr code,it should not affect edit form.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same issue that I was having where this only happened on the second page, I believe SharePoint is pulling in information that isn't being displayed but the script is reading.

Adding in a filter for null rows before your if statement allows the script to run without trying to apply a style to a row that isn't being rendered.  You could combine this with an `&&` in your existing `if` statement.

Option 1:

```
if (row != null) {
    if(dateDue<today&&status!="Complete"){
        row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
if(dateDue<today&&status!="Complete"&&row!=null){
    row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```